# This.props.dispatch not a function - React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I am trying to dispatch an action from within my smart component. I've tried to use the `mapDispatchToProps` and `this.props.dispatch(actions.getApplications(1))` but neither is binding the actions to `props`.

Im not sure if it is because my `mapStateToProps` is not included? I tried to include it but it did not work either.

Any help is appreciated, I apologize for the length of the code block below.

```
import classNames from 'classnames';
import SidebarMixin from 'global/jsx/sidebar_component';

import Header from 'common/header';
import Sidebar from 'common/sidebar';
import Footer from 'common/footer';
import AppCard from 'routes/components/appCard';
import { getApplications } from 'redux/actions/appActions';

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

import actions from 'redux/actions';
import { VisibilityFilters } from 'redux/actions/actionTypes';


class ApplicationContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      applicants: []
    }

    this.onDbLoad = this.onDbLoad.bind(this)

  }
  onDbLoad(){
    console.log(this.props.dispatch)
     // this.props.getApplications(1)
  }

    render() {
    return (
        <Col sm={12} md={4} lg={4}>
            <PanelContainer style={panelStyle}>
                <Panel>
                    <PanelBody >
                        <Grid>
                            <Row>
                              { this.onDbLoad() }
                            </Row>
                      </Grid>
                    </PanelBody>
                </Panel>
            </PanelContainer>
        </Col>
    )}
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){

  return bindActionCreators({ getApplications: getApplications },dispatch)
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ApplicationContainer);

@SidebarMixin
export default class extends React.Component {

    render() {
    const app = ['Some text', 'More Text', 'Even More Text'];

        var classes = classNames({
            'container-open': this.props.open
        })
        return (
            <Container id='container' className={classes}>
                <Sidebar />
                <Header />
        <Container id='body'>
          <Grid>
            <Row>
              <ApplicationContainer />
            </Row>
          </Grid>
        </Container>
                <Footer />
            </Container>
    )}
}
```

Answer (score 78):

Per the Redux FAQ question at [here](https://redux.js.org/faq/react-redux#why-don-t-i-have-thispropsdispatch-available-in-my-connected-component), `this.props.dispatch` is available by **default** if you ***do not*** supply your own `mapDispatchToProps` function.  If you *do* supply a `mapDispatchToProps` function, you are responsible for returning a prop named `dispatch` yourself:

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
   ...other methods,
   dispatch                // ← Add this
})

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Component)
```

Or, you can make sure your action creators are pre-bound using Redux's [`bindActionCreators`](https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators) utility, and skip having to worry about using `this.props.dispatch` in your component.

Comment: thanks for the response. My `mapDispatchToProps` returns the `bindActionCreators`

Answer (score 48):

As you mentioned in your question, `mapDispatchToProps` should be the *second* argument to `connect`.

If you don't have any state mapping to be done, you can pass `null` as the first argument:

```
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ApplicationContainer);
```

After you do this, then `this.props.getApplications` will be bound.

---

As per your comment, if you want to have access to `this.props.dispatch` INSTEAD of binding actions, simply call `connect()` without passing any mappers, and the default behavior will inject `dispatch`.

If you want to have BOTH bound action creators and `this.props.dispatch`, you need to add a `dispatch` to the object that you pass to `mapDispatchToProps` as well. Something like `dispatch: action => action`. Or, since you're not putting everything under a root key (like `actions`), you could do:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  let actions = bindActionCreators({ getApplications });
  return { ...actions, dispatch };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I've tried your solution as well but dispatch still doesn't show up as a `prop`.

Comment: Are you specifically wanting to use `dispatch` generically? Or do you want your other action to be bound. If the former, I can update the answer.

Comment: I am wanting to dispatch an action so that it will be ran through the reducers.

Comment: So normally you would use a bound action instead of manually calling `this.props.dispatch`. Are you wanting to manually generate an action?

Comment: Yes I'd like to generate an action on component render

Comment: looks this way  return bindActionCreators ({getApplications}, dispatch ); you can do it too

Comment: What about when you want to have have BOTH bound action creators and `this.props.dispatch` available and your mapDispatchToProps is an object instead of a function?