# "this.props.dispatch" dispatching wrong action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm exporting a component without mapping dispatch to props like this, [in order to make dispatch available by default to props.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850988/this-props-dispatch-not-a-function-react-redux):

```
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(Radium(ClientList));
```

I have the following action creator:

```
export function organizeDownloadableClientCustomerData(downloadableClientCustomerData) {
    return {
        type: 'ORGANIZE_DOWNLOADABLE_CLIENT_PAGE_DATA',
        downloadableClientCustomerData: downloadableClientCustomerData
    }
}
```

When I dispatch it:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(this.fetchCustomerData());
}
```

It dispatches the first action I've defined on `actions.js`:

```
export const navigate = eventLink => {
    return {
        type: 'NAVIGATE',
        eventLink: eventLink
    }
}
```

[image]

Which makes no sense *at all*. I know I should be making API requests far away from componentDidMount with fancy redux-saga, but I'm getting there. Funny thing is, if I dispatch it like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch({
        type: 'ORGANIZE_DOWNLOADABLE_CLIENT_PAGE_DATA',
        downloadableClientCustomerData: downloadableClientCustomerData
    });
}
```

It works like a charm. Why it dispatches a wrong action if it's through an action creator???

EDIT (fetchCustomerData):

```
fetchCustomerData() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_DOWNLOADABLE_CLIENT_CUSTOMER_DATA_BEGIN' });
        return fetch(`${backendAddress}/fetch_customers/?acquirer=${this.props.storeState.currentAcquirer}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(responseData => {
                dispatch({
                    type: 'FETCH_DOWNLOADABLE_CLIENT_CUSTOMER_DATA_SUCCESS',
                    responseData: responseData
                });
                this.fitDataIntoPages(this.props.storeState.downloadableClientCustomerData.responseData);
                return true;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                dispatch({
                    type: 'FETCH_DOWNLOADABLE_CLIENT_CUSTOMER_DATA_ERROR',
                    payload: { error }
                });
                return false;
            });
    };
}
```

EDIT2:

```
fitDataIntoPages(data) {
    ...
    let downloadableClientCustomerData = {
        responseData: data,
        organizedData: organizedData,
        customerElements: customerElements,
        totalItems: totalItems,
        numberOfPages: Math.ceil(totalItems / this.props.storeState.downloadableClientCustomerData.pageCount)
    }
    this.props.dispatch(organizeDownloadableClientCustomerData(downloadableClientCustomerData));
}
```

Comment: This is too little to work with. We are left with giving you debugging tips. What could dispatch the navigate action? And have you tried setting breakpoints right after the success call, the navigate action, in the `fitDataIntoPages` function, etc, so you can see in which order stuff is happening and if your functions are called as you expect?

Comment: In Redux DevTools, look at the view of what is in the data for the unexpected `NAVIGATE` action by selecting `Action` in the upper right and then click on the `NAVIGATE` action on the left. Check if the type is the only thing wrong or if the rest of the data is for the `NAVIGATE` action as well.

Comment: Also show your import of `organizeDownloadableClientCustomerData`.

Comment: @RyanCogswell, the data is definitely wrong. It's sending data of 'ORGANIZE_DOWNLOADABLE_CLIENT_PAGE_DATA' to 'NAVIGATE'. The import is `import organizeDownloadableClientCustomerData from "../../actions.js";`, which corresponds directly to the correct Action Creator. It makes no sense.

Comment: @oligofren, I've included a breakpoint right before the dispatch inside `fitDataIntoPages` and it clearly shows going to the Navigate Action. My only guess is that by not defining `mapDispatchToProps`, it's mapping the actions wrong. Either that, or middleware hell (Thunk / Saga), which should not be the reason.

Comment: Your import looks like it is missing curly braces. If it is, then it will use the default export. Babel might also do wonky stuff in this case, if you are missing an explicit default.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe it!!! I've changed the import just to test the luck after @Ryan Cogswell asked, from `import organizeDownloadableClientCustomerData from "../../actions.js";` to `import { organizeDownloadableClientCustomerData } from "../../actions.js";` and just bloody worked!!! (It dispatched the correct action) I've lost almost a whole day of work because of this.