# Trying to save value to redux store - getting dispatch is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to save a value to a redux store upon a user entering text for a search.

Edited to include my full import list

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import API from './API';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import searchSave from '../actions/search'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'
const format = require('string-format')

class Search extends Component {
...

   searchForText = (text) => {
    console.log("user stopped typing");
    console.log(text);
    this.props.searchSave(text);
  }

...
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    oidc: state.oidc,
    search: state.searchtext,
  };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  let actions = bindActionCreators({ searchSave });
  return { ...actions, dispatch };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Search)
```

My reducer looks like this and is in my combineReducers function elsewhere:

```
import Actions from '../actions/search.js'

export default (state = "", action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case Actions.SEARCH:
        return {searchtext: action.payload}
      }
      return state;
    };
```

I am getting the error, "TypeError: Dispatch is not a function" - but theoretically dispatch should be bound by bindActionCreators?

I have searched for this exact error, but none of it seems related to my specific conditions.

I am assuming I am doing something wrong in my mapStateToProps or my reducer?

I am pretty new to redux and still find it somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `dispatch` function as the second parameter to `bindActionCreators`:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ searchSave }, dispatch);
}
```

You can see the docs for this here: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch

If your intention was to also include `dispatch` in the returned props (which seems like an antipattern to me, but I'm not an expert), your original code works with the addition of the second parameter to `bindActionCreators`:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  const actions = bindActionCreators({ searchSave }, dispatch);
  return { ...actions, dispatch };
}
```

Comment: Yes, that gets rid of the error. Though for some reason my state isn't updating, despite the payload and the action type triggering.

Comment: Also this is where I got the pattern initially - not sure if it is an anti-pattern or not - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850988/this-props-dispatch-not-a-function-react-redux

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the import for connect, and some stuff in mapDispatchToProps. I also don't believe you need bindActionCreators in this scenario:

```
import searchSave from '../actions/search'
//Missing import connect
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Search extends Component {
...

   searchForText = (text) => {
    console.log("user stopped typing");
    console.log(text);
    this.props.searchSave(text);
  }

...
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    oidc: state.oidc,
    search: state.searchtext,
  };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    searchSave: (inputs) => dispatch(searchSave(inputs)
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Search)
```