# mapDispatchToProps didnt work in my project

Tags: reactjs, redux

im newbie to implement redux-offline in my project. I follow the [documentation](https://redux-offline.github.io/redux-offline/docs/basics/commit), and its work, but didnt work like this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850988/this-props-dispatch-not-a-function-react-redux). But whats wrong in my project, here my code:

To take a action with endpoint

getBookList = async () => {
const URL = ENDPOINT_LARAVEL.BIBLE_BOOK + '?abbreviation=' + this.props.selectedBibleId
const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('token')
this.toggleLoading(false)

```
this.props.dispatch({
  type: BIBLE_BOOK_LIST_REQUEST,
  meta: {
    offline: {
      effect: {
        url: URL,
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json', 
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      },
      commit: { type: BIBLE_BOOK_LIST_COMMIT },
      rollback: { type: BIBLE_BOOK_LIST_ROLLBACK },
    },
  },
})

this.setState({ bibleBookListFiltered: this.props.bibleBookList })
return
```

}

Here the function to store in Redux:

```
 storeBibleSelection = async () => {
    const selectedBookId = this.state.selectedBookId
    const selectedBookIndex = this.state.selectedBookIndex
    const selectedBookName = this.state.selectedBookName

    await this.props.saveSelectedBookId(selectedBookId)
    await this.props.saveSelectedBookIndex(selectedBookIndex)
    await this.props.saveSelectedBookName(selectedBookName)
  }
```

If I running the option A, I cant write my selected to store, if i running the option B, I cant read the data from store

```
// OPTION A: CANNOT WRITE IN STORE
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    saveSelectedBookId,
    saveSelectedBookIndex,
    saveSelectedBookName,
    dispatch
})

// OPTION B: CANNOT READ FROM STORE
// function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
//   return bindActionCreators({
//       saveSelectedBookId,
//       saveSelectedBookIndex,
//       saveSelectedBookName,
//   }, dispatch)
// }

function mapStateToProps({ LanguageReducer, BibleReducer, UserSettingReducer }) {
  return {
    languagePack: LanguageReducer.languagePack,
    selectedBookIndex: BibleReducer.selectedBookIndex,
    selectedChapterIndex: BibleReducer.selectedChapterIndex,
    selectedVerseIndex: BibleReducer.selectedVerseIndex,
    selectedBookId: BibleReducer.selectedBookId,
    selectedBibleId: BibleReducer.selectedBibleId,
    selectedBookName: BibleReducer.selectedBookName,
    bibleBookList: BibleReducer.bibleBookList,
    globalFontSetting: UserSettingReducer.globalFontSetting,
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BibleVerseSelectionScreen)
```

any suggestion or code i need to show? please help, thank you